# CSS + .MOV Object

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I've created a page that uses jquery to slide from left to right displaying content in the middle of the page, everything around the centre is hidden via "overflow: hidden" which works a charm, until I embedded via the  tags a quicktime video, it isn't hidden / it is always visible. I have no idea why this is happening and would love to get help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without seeing the code in question, but depending on the method you are using in jquery to insert the embed tags, you may be replacing the element that has been hidden (this can happen if you use replace, as the element is physically replaced with the new embed tags).